# Explanation of a stratified randomization algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithms

In the book: *Monte Carlo Simulation for Pharmaceutical Industry Concepts, Algorithms, and Case Studies*, there is an algorithm for generating stratified randomizations:

[image]

1. What is the U_c(nG) notation? What is c and how is this notation different from the standard U[a,b] notation for uniform distributions?
2. In the pseudocode above, what is i defined as? The highlighted term is ambiguous: x cannot be <= i/nG and > i/nG at the same time.

Comment: The highlighted inequality is probably a typographical error: the first "$i$" likely is intended to be $i-1.$  But the notation in this algorithm is so obscure and cumbersome, and the algorithm is so badly set out (*e.g.*, why use a quadruple loop to express a simple idea that requires no looping at all?) that on that basis alone you might want to consider using some other source of information about that material.

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair over this. Do you have any recommendation on texts that covers randomization algorithms in trial designs? Also, what do you think  U_c( . ) notation stands for?

Comment: It's likely referring to a continuous uniform distribution on the interval from $0$ to $nG.$  This appears to be an extremely inefficient way to implement a standard mechanism to select one element randomly from $\{1,2,\ldots, nG\}.$  For recommendations, consider asking a question requesting recommendations.  Be specific about what you're looking for an the intended level of the audience.